# Jquery Element Not Performing Correctly

Tags: jquery

I've been developing a new website for my freelancing and have decided to try using appengine for the first time.

I followed this tutorial http://www.gayadesign.com/diy/text-with-moving-backgrounds-with-jquery/ but couldn't seem to get it to move on chidsterdesign.com

Comment: You will need to provide a lot more information if you don't want to be down voted. What have tried.  Secondly it has nothing to do with appengine.

Comment: It is hosted on appengine and as appengine has restrictions on languages & files that are supported, I didn't know if that could have been apart of the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to place the Jquery script first so instead of

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/move-bg.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

use

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/move-bg.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks man, it's always the little things that are the undoings of stuff like this

Comment: No problem, glad i could help. It's best when something in javascript/jquery doesn't work, to see if there's an error in the console ;)